# CryptoJS Sha3 and PHP-SHA3

Tags: php, hash, cryptojs, sha-3

I'm trying to get the same result from using cryptojs sha3 method and the php-sha3 library, but the results just dont' seem to match.

An example:

For CryptoJS

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3("qwerty", { outputLength: 224 }).toString();
```

gives me `d7a12ecec4442f1b31eea5f7d5470f0ca6169463e09d91a147c3b8e8`

while with PHP-SHA3

```
echo sha3("qwerty",224);
```

gives me `13783bdfa4a63b202d9aa1992eccdd68a9fa5e44539273d8c2b797cd`

I am a complete encryption noob, so I'm guessing I'm missing something fundamental about this.

Comment: I've read something about SHA-3 being implemented in CryptoJS before it was finalized. It may produce different results.

Comment: Just out of interest where are you getting sha3 from for PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly got it from https://github.com/strawbrary/php-sha3

Comment: By the way, you could verify your sha3 value online from https://fe-tool.com/en-us/hash/sha3?inputText=qwerty

Answer (score 6):

CryptoJS 'sha3' is not actually using the current SHA-3 standard unfortunately - hence your discrepancy. The code is implementing a version of SHA-3 which was superseded.

> In 2014, NIST made slight changes to the Keccak submission and
>   published FIPS 202, which became the official SHA-3 standard in August
>   2015.

Quoted from this source:

https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/are-you-really-using-sha-3-or-old-code-c5df31ad2b0

Which goes on to say:

> Unfortunately, the readme in Github makes no mention, and the user
>   must look at the old site to find the “NOTE: I made a mistake when I
>   named this implementation SHA-3. It should be named Keccak.” So any
>   dependents of CryptoJS that uses sha3 is using old code that would be
>   better described by a term like Keccak. Also, beware of online sha3
>   calculators, because some of them have not been updated to SHA-3.

Answer (score 1):

Artjom is right.  You can try this JS library, https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3.  I am able to use it to generate SHA3 and Keccak hashes.

The you can verify the hash at http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_224.html.

Comment: Used also with good results.